# Puppeteer unable to click on the Allow button in Google consent page

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer to login to Google Auth page. So far I was able to make puppeteer enter the username, password and 2FA successfully. Then I get redirected to this Google consent page

[image]

But puppeteer fails to click on the Allow button and throws the following error:

```
typing email...
clicking next button...
waiting for password field...
typing password...
clicking next button...
waiting for consent approval...
clicking Allow button...
(node:87043) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: #submit_approve_access
    at assert (/Users/mohamed/projects/googleAuth/api/src/test/resources/dev-tools/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:278:11)
    at Frame.click (/Users/mohamed/projects/googleAuth/api/src/test/resources/dev-tools/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:736:5)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (/Users/mohamed/projects/googleAuth/api/src/test/resources/dev-tools/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:144:27)
    at Page.click (/Users/mohamed/projects/googleAuth/api/src/test/resources/dev-tools/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:973:29)
    at doLogin (/Users/mohamed/projects/googleAuth/api/src/test/resources/dev-tools/routes/index.js:177:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:87043) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:87043) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Below is the Node.js code that I wrote:

```
async function doLogin(authorizeUrl) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(authorizeUrl);
    await page.mainFrame().waitForSelector('#identifierId');
    console.log('typing email...');
    await page.type('#identifierId', googleCredentials.username);
    await page.mainFrame().waitForSelector('#identifierNext');
    console.log('clicking next button...');
    await page.click('#identifierNext');
    console.log('waiting for password field...');
    await page
        .mainFrame()
        .waitForSelector('#password input[type="password"]', {visible: true});
    console.log('typing password...');
    await page.type('#password input[type="password"]', googleCredentials.password, {
        delay: 100,
    });
    console.log('clicking next button...');
    await page.click('#passwordNext', {delay: 100});
    console.log('waiting for consent approval...');
    console.log('clicking Allow button...');
    await page.click('#submit_approve_access', {delay: 100});
    return browser;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `page.waitForSelector('#submit_approve_access')` before pressing click?

Comment: Thanks a lot @ThomasDondorf , that solved the issue. I am wondering why do I need to add `page.waitForSelector` for this specific button, cause for the other buttons I didn't need to add it?

Comment: There is probably some action happening in the background (maybe a network request?) which will cause a delay of a few milliseconds before the button is displayed. I added it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button is not available yet when you click on it. This is probably the case because when you click on the `#passwordNext` button, the page will execute an asynchronous action which might take a few milliseconds, maybe a network request, maybe just some calculations. Therefore, without waiting, when you call `page.click` there is no button to click.

**Solution**

You can add the following line before calling `page.click` to make sure the button is actually present on the page:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('#submit_approve_access');
```